# Error while executing hql query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I am getting an error while executing a hql query using

```
Query query = session.createQuery(q);
```

My query is

```
select AU_USER from AU_TABLE where AU_ID in(010012025160151756912703600209,010012025160150254316794700103)
```

The stacktrace is

```
2018-07-06 11:25:05 ERROR ErrorCounter:54 - line 1:74: unexpected token: 912703600209
2018-07-06 11:25:05 ERROR ErrorCounter:50 - line 1:74: unexpected token: 912703600209
line 1:74: unexpected token: 912703600209
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2456)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2336)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2011)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.compoundExpr(HqlBaseParser.java:3062)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.inList(HqlBaseParser.java:2884)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2456)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2336)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2011)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whereClause(HqlBaseParser.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
    at com.adeptia.dao.MigrationDao.getIndigoUsersBySchemaIds(MigrationDao.java:1096)
    at com.adeptia.dao.MigrationDao.main(MigrationDao.java:1120)
2018-07-06 11:25:05 WARN  HqlParser:259 - HHH000203: processEqualityExpression() : No expression to process!
2018-07-06 11:25:05 ERROR ErrorCounter:54 - line 1:109: unexpected token: 94700103
2018-07-06 11:25:05 ERROR ErrorCounter:50 - line 1:109: unexpected token: 94700103
line 1:109: unexpected token: 94700103
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2456)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2336)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2011)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.compoundExpr(HqlBaseParser.java:3069)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.inList(HqlBaseParser.java:2884)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2456)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2420)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2336)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2011)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whereClause(HqlBaseParser.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
    at com.adeptia.dao.MigrationDao.getIndigoUsersBySchemaIds(MigrationDao.java:1096)
    at com.adeptia.dao.MigrationDao.main(MigrationDao.java:1120)
2018-07-06 11:25:05 WARN  HqlParser:259 - HHH000203: processEqualityExpression() : No expression to process!
```

Comment: what type of `AU_ID`?

Comment: it is a 30 digit varchar id

Comment: try to use `String q="select AU_USER from AU_TABLE where AU_ID in('010012025160151756912703600209', '010012025160150254316794700103')";` note the single quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved using createSQLQuery instead of createQuery

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing your sql query like this:

```
String q="select AU_USER from AU_TABLE where AU_ID in(010012025160151756912703600209,010012025160150254316794700103)";
```

then try this code:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(q.toString());
```

I hope your problem is solved. if still getting the problem then post query again.

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and the OP's solution?

Comment: `.toString()` is obsolete, if `q` is a String anyways.